# Removing colours from heading levels in org

Tags: faces

I want to understand the problem outlined by the debugger.

Am using the following  to set the colours for the heading levels.

```
(defun komis-luna-hglevel-addtfc ()
  "Set foreground colours of headings according to level."

  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-1 '(:foreground "cyan1"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-2 '(:foreground "chartreuse"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-3 '(:foreground "dark orange"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-4 '(:foreground "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-5 '(:foreground "magenta"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-6 '(:foreground "tan1"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-7 '(:foreground "deep sky blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-8 '(:foreground "orange red")) )
```

Then try to remove them when the minor mode is disabled using

```
(defun komis-luna-hglevel-rmvtfc ()
  "Remove the typeface previously added for org-level-N faces."

  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-1)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-2)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-3)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-4)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-5)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-6)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-7)
  (face-remap-remove-relative 'org-level-8))
```

Here is the debugger result

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp org-level-1)
  face-remap-remove-relative(org-level-1)
  komis-luna-hglevel-rmvtfc()
  (if komis-minor-mode (progn (komis-luna-hglevel-addtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-text) (font-lock-add-keywords nil $keyword) (font-lock-fontify-buffer)) (komis-luna-hglevel-rmvtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-clear) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (font-lock-remove-keywords nil $keyword) (while (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t) (decompose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))) (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))
  (let* (($keyword '(("^\\*+ " (0 (let* ... ... ... ... ... ... nil)))))) (if komis-minor-mode (progn (komis-luna-hglevel-addtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-text) (font-lock-add-keywords nil $keyword) (font-lock-fontify-buffer)) (komis-luna-hglevel-rmvtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-clear) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (font-lock-remove-keywords nil $keyword) (while (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t) (decompose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))) (font-lock-fontify-buffer))) (message "keyword: %S" $keyword))
  (let ((last-message (current-message))) (setq komis-minor-mode (cond ((eq arg 'toggle) (not komis-minor-mode)) ((and (numberp arg) (< arg 1)) nil) (t t))) (if (boundp 'local-minor-modes) (progn (setq local-minor-modes (delq 'komis-minor-mode local-minor-modes)) (if komis-minor-mode (progn (setq local-minor-modes (cons 'komis-minor-mode local-minor-modes)))))) (let* (($keyword '(("^\\*+ " (0 ...))))) (if komis-minor-mode (progn (komis-luna-hglevel-addtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-text) (font-lock-add-keywords nil $keyword) (font-lock-fontify-buffer)) (komis-luna-hglevel-rmvtfc) (komis-luna-emphasis-clear) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (font-lock-remove-keywords nil $keyword) (while (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t) (decompose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))) (font-lock-fontify-buffer))) (message "keyword: %S" $keyword)) (run-hooks 'komis-minor-mode-hook (if komis-minor-mode 'komis-minor-mode-on-hook 'komis-minor-mode-off-hook)) (if (called-interactively-p 'any) (progn nil (if (and (current-message) (not (equal last-message (current-message)))) nil (let ((local " in current buffer")) (message "Komis minor mode %sabled%s" (if komis-minor-mode "en" "dis") local))))))
  komis-minor-mode(toggle)
  funcall-interactively(komis-minor-mode toggle)
  call-interactively(komis-minor-mode record nil)
  command-execute(komis-minor-mode record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "komis-minor-mode" "komis-m")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "komis-minor-mode" "komis-m")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: This is another case where reading the docs answers your question.  `face-remap-add-relative` returns a value (a list of some sort) which you need to save and use as the argument for `face-remap-remove-relative` instead of the symbol you are currently passing.

Comment: Would I need to get the value from each `face-remap-add-relative` call for the various heading levels ?

Comment: *Please* do `C-h f face-remap-remove-relative` and *read* the doc string.

Comment: It looks as so and I also need to have each cookie as a global.

Comment: Would you recommend to set each cookie to `nil` after using it for `face-remap-remove-relative` ?

Comment: In  `komis-luna-hglevel-addtfc`  I have done `(setq cookie-level-1
    (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-1 '(:foreground "cyan1")))`.  Then in `komis-luna-hglevel-tfcrmv` I used the cookie as `(face-remap-remove-relative cookie-level-1)`.

Comment: Make a list `cookie-list` and push the cookies onto it.  Do a `do-list` over the cookies calling `face-remap-remove-relative` on each to remove them.  Thus only one global.

Comment: I've lost count on how many things I've asked you, but this is certainly one: ask a question, get an answer, move on. Do not ask additional questions in comments.